# vertical thumbnail multiple group

Tags: jssor

i want to show different galery in the vertical thumbnails with one slide. I would separate the thumbnails like on this picture:

http://s21.postimg.org/6nvdszkc7/jssor_group_thumbnails.png

Between each group, I would a space (50px in the exemple).

Can you help me?

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
    ...,
    $SpacingY: 50,
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's not what i want. The group1 contain 7 pictures and the group2 contain 4 pictures... I want to view the thumbnails of the first group, a space (50px in my exemple) and the thumbnails of the second group.

Comment: I see. There is no option to do that job. You can create your own thumbnail and detect click on thumbnail, then call jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(index);